# how to print time in python in customized format?

Tags: python

how can I print time in format using python

220429

first two letters are last two digits of 2022, midle one are month and last two are day in a month

Answer (score 2):

You can do so using the `strftime` method on `datetime` objects.

```py
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.now()

d.strftime('%y%m%d') # Outputs '220429'
```

[strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)